# Swift json call returns empty bracket, nil doesnt work to check for it

Tags: swift

So i am making an api call and sometimes the "objects" returns empty brackets

the api call returns the following

```
{"meta":{"status":"OK","count":0,"offset":0,"totalcount":0},"objects":[]}
```

I want the code to be able to notice that the "objects" brackets are empty, and act on it (an if or else statement). But i dont know how to make swift see that the brackets are empty, and "nil" doesnt work.

There is probably a very easy fix for this, but since i am very new to this i really have a hard time finding the solution.

These are my structs (im posting a part of the code, enough so you kinda understand what i need help with):

```
struct media: Codable {
    var webpath:String }

struct Inventory: Codable {
    var instock: Int
    var coordinates: String
    var lastinventory: String }

struct descriptions: Codable {
    var longdescription:String
    var created:String  }

struct main: Codable {
    let displayname:String
    let stock:String
    let inventory: [Inventory]
    let descriptions:[descriptions]
    let media:[media] }

struct json: Codable {
    let objects:[main] } 



 let session = URLSession.shared
        let datatask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            //check for response
            if let response = response
            { //print(response)
                
            }
            
            //check for errors
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                //parse Json
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                
                let newsFeed = try decoder.decode(json.self, from: data!)
                    
              
                    
                    if newsFeed.objects == nil // THIS DOESNT WORK, IT RETURNS PRINT "NOT EMPTY"
                    {
                        print("empty")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("not empty")
                    }
```

Comment: Isn't that the samo-samo asynchronous delivery thing?

Comment: Try `if newsFeed.objects.isEmpty { print("Is empty") }`

Comment: It's not nil, it is am empty array. Check with `.isEmpty` or `.count == 0`

Comment: Thanks alot for the above codes , much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty array is not the same as `nil`.  And in fact you have declared your `objects` property in a way that it *can't* be `nil`.  So to check for an empty array instead you can use:

```
if newsFeed.objects.isEmpty {
   //Do whatever you need here
}
```

Comment: @Axxi This doesn't affect anything, but just because I presume you're a newer Swift dev I'll mention the naming convention thing I see:  Typically we make classes/structs/etc start with upper case, like Media instead of media.  It's what other devs will expect if they go to work on your code.  We also usually name them with the singular form of the noun, like Description instead of Descriptions.  Ignore me if it doesn't matter to you, but just trying to give another little tip.

Comment: Very thankful for the extra tip, ill make sure to keep this in mind.